# How to add Jquery Chosen multiple select to bound CFSELECT?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, jquery-chosen

I need to add a Chosen multi-select to a cfselect that is driven via Bind attribute by another cfselect.

The problem seems to be that when Chosen (and the rest of the page) loads, it has no options for the cfselect, and after the cfselect bind makes some AJAX requests (providing the end cfselect with a new set of data), the Chosen display is not updated accordingly.

Here are my cfselects:

```
<div class="rowalt">
    <p class="_20NP"align="right"><strong>Event:</strong>&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="_70NP" align="left">  
        <cfselect class="chzn-done" name="EH_ID" id="EH_ID" bind="cfc:EventQuickAdd.GetEvent2({EM_ID},{EC_ID})" display="NAME" value="EH_ID" data-placeholder="Choose an Event" required="yes" selected="#eh_id#" /> 
    </p>

</div>

<div class="rowalt">
    <p class="_20NP"align="right"><strong>Event Detail:</strong>&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="_70NP" align="left">  
        <cfselect name="ED_ID" id="ED_ID" bind="cfc:EventQuickAdd.GetEventDetail2({EM_ID},{EC_ID},{EH_ID})" display="NAME" value="ED_ID" data-placeholder="Choose an Event" multiple selected="#ed_id#" />
    </p>                                    
</div>
```

I've been able to use `$('#ED_ID').trigger("liszt:updated")` (using the old version of the Chosen plugin) to update chosen. If I run this code in the console, the Chosen display is updated fine, and is loaded with all of the current option data. However, I cannot figure out how to run this code at the correct time.

If I run the trigger on `$('#EH_ID').change()`, the trigger runs before Coldfusion has a chance to make an AJAX request, and return with the selects new data.

Is there some way to set an async option to false on the Coldfusion AJAX request, so that it will retrieve the information and THEN update the Chosen? Is there another event handler that will fire only after the AJAX request is successful?